# Django template variable not recognized in script tag but recognized in regular h1 tag. what could cause that?

Tags: javascript, django, variables, scope

```
<script>
    var my_data = {{ passed_data }}
</script>

<body>
    <h1>{{ passed_data }}</h1>
</body>
```

This is the basic idea behind the code. I suspect it may be a scope issue

Comment: Is the html page being parsed by the plugin? It's probably thinking the text inside the h1 tag is plain text.

Answer (score 1):

Add quotes to the JS:

```
<script>
    var my_data = "{{ passed_data }}"
<script>
```